# for block inside bash

Tags: bash, shell

This piece of code is working absolutely fine when I am executing it individually

```
for i in {1..13}
do
echo "<td class = 'loop'>

</td>"
done
```

But when I am putting this inside a bash script I am getting only one iteration,instead of 13 iteration.

The whole script looks something like

```
while read variable
do
//something
done<a.txt

for i in {1..13}
do
echo "<td class = 'loop'>

</td>"
done
```

Can any one help me out.

*EDIT*

```
     #/!/bin/bash
while read  host 
do  



    y=$(($y+1)) 

    count=$(ping -c $COUNT $host | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')
    if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
                if [ -n "$host" ]; then
                    echo "<td class ='statuscellred'>" >>table1.html
                    echo  "$host" | cut -d'.' -f1 >> table1.html
                    echo "</td>" >> table1.html
                    if [ $(($y % 13)) -eq 0 ] ; then
                        echo "</tr>">>table1.html
                        echo "<tr>">>table1.html
                    fi  
                else
                    echo "<td class ='statuscellblanck'>" >>table1.html
                    echo "$host" >> table1.html
                    echo "</td>" >> table1.html
                    if [ $(($y % 13)) -eq 0 ] ; then
                        echo "</tr>">>table1.html
                        echo "<tr>">>table1.html
                    fi
                fi

    else
        if [ -n "$host" ]; then
                    echo "<td class ='statuscellgreen'>" >>table1.html
                    echo  "$host" | cut -d'.' -f1 >> table1.html
                    echo "</td>" >> table1.html
                    if [ $(($y % 13)) -eq 0 ] ; then
                        echo "</tr>">>table1.html
                        echo "<tr>">>table1.html
                    fi  
                else
                    echo "<td class ='statuscellblanck'>" >>table1.html
                    echo "$host" >> table1.html
                    echo "</td>" >> table1.html
                    if [ $(($y % 13)) -eq 0 ] ; then
                        echo "</tr>">>table1.html
                        echo "<tr>">>table1.html
                    fi
                fi
    fi




done < server1.txt

for i in {1..13}
do
echo "<td class = 'loop'>

</td>">>table1.html
done
```

and here is server1.txt

```
     1.com
2.com
3.com
4.com
5.com

7.com
8.com


9.com

11.com

13.com

15.com
```

Comment: I usually do `for i in $(seq 1 13)` and I'm sure that it works.

Comment: the actual code is bigger than this.But logic part is this much only.Do you want me to paste the entire code?

Comment: @ArjunShankar the block is replaced by //something.Which is not needed in this case I believe.

Comment: What does your shebang line look like? Are you using /bin/bash or /bin/sh? bash in sh mode won't expand {1..13}.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the script is being executed by bash, and not another shell?  Try adding a shebang line (#!/bin/bash) as the first line.

Comment: Try and paste a http://sscce.org/ i.e. the minimal script that we can try, which still produces your problem. Pasting something here which does not get interpreted, something that does, but doesn't produce a problem isn't going to be helpful.

Comment: FatalError and dj_segfault have caught it, most probably.

Comment: Edited the code which is now a sscce.

Comment: Works for me as written.

Comment: Your shebang line is not a shebang line. It should be `#!/bin/bash` (you have an extra `/`). And, you should not have space before the `#`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the posted code, the shebang line is not formed correctly.  It should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

with no leading spaces (posted version has an extra `/` in it).  As it stands, if you execute that in a shell it'll be interpreted by the current shell, and the first line is merely a comment.

[taken from my comment as it appears to have resolved the OP's problem]